# Algebra word problem involving money system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

A person has 25 bills of different types, some \$1 bills some \$5 bills some \$10 bills some \$20 bills. The total value of the bills is \$140. There are 2 times as many \$1 bills as \$10 bills and 2 fewer \$5 bills as \$1 bills. The rest are \$20 bills. How many of each bills does he have..... I know the answer but I want to know the math behind it can someone show work and tell me

Answer (score 3):

$x = $ # of ten dollar bills
$2x = $ # of 1 dollar bills
$2x - 2 = $ # of 5 dollar bills
$25 - x - 2x - (2x + 2) = $ # of 20 dollar bills
so $140 = 1(2x) + 5(2x - 2) + 10x + 20(25 - x - 2x -(2x + 2))$

Solve for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The following image shows another way to represent the problem in terms of algebraic symbols. It includes manipulations of the symbols to arrive at the solution. "The math" behind the manipulations are the "generally accepted definitions, laws, and theorems" for the set of Integers. [The image is also available in PDF format](http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/Reply$1446441075.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Consider using LaTeX, your life will be easier for it.